# How is the setting of the the PyPDFLoader encoding using DirectoryLoader Langchain class

Tags: python, pypdf, langchain

I'm using QARetrievalChain from Langchain, by getting context from pdf with spanish language.

Using PyPDFLoader with DirectoryLoader, i'm getting issues when using an LLM 'cause is getting context with text in some parts encoded in unicode. Someone knows how is the setting of the unicode using the DirectoryLoader from Langchain to something like utf-8?

Thanks!

Comment: can you please paste your code and explain the error message clearly